# Prestashop product link unwanted characters in the end of the link

Tags: php, e-commerce, prestashop

I have a problem in my product page..i enabled clean url, it works fine but the link is showing some unwanted characters, and I don't know what to do. I don't know where to fix it..
this is how the link looks like

Default theme: `http://localhost/site/multan/18-ahar.html#/fiber-wool_silk/size-10_x_14_/construction-machine_knotted`
unwanted words are after '#'

Custome theme: `http://localhost/site/multan/18-ahar.html#.UiPzAtISZng`
unwanted words are after '#'

I want to show just like this `http://localhost/site/multan/18-ahar.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These "unwanted characters" are used by JavaScript on your page to determine which combination of product attributes customer selects. I don't think this is an error, as the link fully describes the product.

If you need need to get rid of the URL hash part (characters after #) you have to create another mechanism for product attribute selection.

Comment: You will have to change product.tpl and CartController.php files in Prestashop and implement your own product attribute combination selection, which isn't a hour job. If you do so you will lose the possibility to load a page with specific product attribute combination, because the default one will be displayed to the customer when he clicks a link from his cart, email, Facebook, etc.